# Force jQuery show/hide to respect display: table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, show, show-hide

I have a bit of css:

```
div { display: table; }

$("div").hide();
$("button").click(function(){
    $("div").show();
});
```

This works perfectly. When it triggers show/hide it will toggle none/table like it's supposed to. However, when loading the page, it's taking a second for the div.hide portion to trigger and the element is visible for a split second. It looks bad so I need to add `display: none` in order to prevent that brief flash. The problem is now it will always return the element as `display: block` after. I know this is because jQuery is toggling the initial state and so having none instead of table means it will revert to standard div display.

So how do you specifically set `display: table` when show/hide triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class on click before showing the div which sets display to table.
I have made a JSFiddle. Please check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsingh2003/nznzbobo/2/) if it fits your requirements

Click handler changes to

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $("div").addClass('DispTable');
    $("div").show(500);
});
```

and in css

```
.DispTable {
    display:table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$('div').css('display', 'table');`. Hope it helps :)

Just for some more detail, another option generally, when hiding and showing elements, is to use the CSS `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible`. These work differently to display as  the element is hidden but the page is as if the element was there.